# Can TextView autoLink and setMovementMethod both be made to work

Tags: android

A number of discussions on here going back years related to getting hyperlinks to work in a TextView. The conclusion is that *autoLink* works for parsing out URLs that are simply embedded in the text, e.g., "go to www.google.com". Then there is

```
setMovememtMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

that will cause actual HTML tags to work, e.g. **<a href="http://www.google.com">go to Google</a>**. However, using the latter causes autoLink to *not* work in the same view.

My issue is that I am displaying text that is supplied by a user database, so I have no control over the formatting. In some cases, this text has plaintext links while in others it is entered as HTML tags. Is there any way to get *both* types of links to work at the same time?

Comment: Could you do something as simple as parse the text for `<a href=` and then choose one of the two based on that?

Comment: Yes, that's my first fallback, but I was wondering if there was an even lazier way to do it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Both plain text links & links with HTML tags will work with the below code

TexView in xml

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txt_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000"
android:textColorLink="#06b" />
```

Here in activity.java

```
String text = "this is the link with anchor tag <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a>. here is the plain text link http://www.google.com";
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_view);
    textView.setText(getParsedLinks(text));
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

instead of using android:autoLink="all" in xml or Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL) use Linkify.addLinks to SpannableString as in below method

```
SpannableString getParsedLinks(String txt){
    Spanned span = Html.fromHtml(txt);
    URLSpan[] urlSpans = span.getSpans(0, span.length(), URLSpan.class);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(span);
    Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.ALL);
    for (URLSpan urlSpan : urlSpans) {
        s.setSpan(urlSpan, span.getSpanStart(urlSpan), span.getSpanEnd(urlSpan), 0);
    }
    return s;
}
```